# Failed to set 'pythonPath'. Error: Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was trying to run and debug my very first program in Python, so my Visual Studio asks me to define a Python interpreter. I selected one, and my VS Code comes with this error. It might be in settings.json, but I don't' know how to solve it. Please help! I put the errors of settings.json and defaultsettings.json here, but again, I don't know how to solve these.

[Default_Settings_Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjUO4.png); [Default_Settings_Error_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN8Mf.png); [Default_Settings_Error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRKkw.png); [Settings_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcvWF.png)

Answer (score 5):

I just fixed the same issue on my computer. It was a missing curly brace in the settings.json file. Open your settings and click on the open settings.json in the top right corner. Once you open it you should see the red error at the last curly brace. Insert another curly brace before it and save, that should fix the issue.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot to enhance the clarity of your answer? Cheers!

Comment: Where do you find or open that 'settings.json' file?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same issue. It was a missing comma in the settings.json file. Open your .json file , you should see the red error. Insert a comma the line before last and save it, that should fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).